# How do I merge two tables in SQL Server SPECIFICALLY using Windows Forms C# and not SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have two tables:

`StudentSection1` with the following columns and information:

```
StudentID (int)(PK)     StudentName (varchar(100))     StudentGender (varchar(100))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                       Henry                          Male    
2                       Scarlette                      Female
```

`StudentSection2` with the following columns and information:

```
StudentID (int)(PK)     StudentName (varchar(100))     StudentGender (varchar(100))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                       Jack                           Male    
2                       Elizabeth                      Female
```

Desired Result:

```
 StudentID    StudentName     StudentGender
 ------------------------------------------
     1        Henry           Male    
     2        Scarlette       Female
     1        Jack            Male    
     2        Elizabeth       Female
```

Name of database: `StudentDB`

I know that there are related questions here, but all I see are answers that only cater to manipulating SQL directly and not Windows Forms and C#. And I know that there Student ID's should be different, but let's just say each section has it's own ID numbers for it's students (as impossible as it may seem)

Anyway, what I want to know is how I can manipulate this in Winforms (not in SQL Server) in such a way that when I press a button in windows form, it will merge both tables together PERMANENTLY in SQL Server. I would prefer if maybe `StudentSection2` is combined into `StudentSection1`, but any workaround is fine.

I'm pretty sure this involves code which contains a connection string etc, but I'm not really sure about this area. Any help would be really useful, thank you very much guys.

Comment: By "merge", do you mean add the rows from the second table to the first?

Comment: Hi Rhumborl, well I guess it's fine if sql is involved, what I meant is, instead of merging the two tables by running a query in sql server, I want to merge both tables using c#, if that makes sense :3

Comment: Your options are to either use SQL or to use something that will create the SQL for you like Entity Framework.  If this is just a one time update just use SSMS to do it.

Comment: @user3289917 the question is WHY do you want to do it in C#? In the end it has to go back to the database. It's added and unnecessary data transmission.

Comment: Hi Amy, I've updated my wanted outcome, I apologize if my meaning of "merge" was vague.

Comment: Your desired result is impossible due to primary key violations.

Comment: @user3289917 every data modification you make on a table is performed using SQL. It doesn't matter which client calls that SQL statement. That's what makes this question unclear, despite the edit.

Comment: @user3289917 besides, the result you show needs no merging at all. The result *concatenates* the data from the two tables. You only need a UNION ALL to do that in SQL. On the client, a siimple `collection1.Concat(collection2)` will concatenate whatever collection you used to retrieve the rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's the colloquial usage of "merge", not the formal usage.

Comment: @user3289917Are you asking how to call SQL from the Window Form?

Comment: @SunMaungOo hello, I think that would be easier, if so, how will I be able to do that?

Comment: I can't stress this enough; you're going to have to learn SQL, database connection string syntax, etc.   The reason you're seeing "purely SQL" answers is because all a C# program does is invoke an SQL statement in the database to do the work, even if it's wrapped in syntactic sugar like Linq.  Most programs in the wild contain the queries as a string of SQL in their code.

Comment: @CDove Ah I see, that makes sense. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Thank you for all of your replies, I may have misunderstood the concept of manipulating sql server with c#. Will plan on studying more about this, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use some SQL within your C# code that executes on the server, or you can use Linq To SQL, Linq To EF which in turn would write the SQL for you behind the scenes. Thinking about efficiency, doing this with some SQL would be the desired way. Let's say you want that result in a new table called AllSections, your code would look like:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=myDatabase"))
{
    string sql = @"Select * into AllSections
    from (
        select * from StudentSection1
        union all
        select * from StudentSection2
    ) tmp;";

    con.Open();
    new SqlCommand(sql, con).ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute an SQL in C#, you will need to know about [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).
It take an connection string in a constructor which is basically a string telling how you will connect to the database.

For example

```
string connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True";
```

Data Source tell you where your database server is located.

Initial Catalog is the name of the database you want to connect to and the last part is the security component to connect the database server.

After you have the created your `SqlConnection` object , you can use [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) which allow you to execute your SQL command.

Do not forget to close your `SqlConnection` object after you have finish using it.